# Using loops how would I take the mean of 3 values within each row?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement

I'm given a matrix similar to this but longer. I ignore the `nan` values when calculating the average. 
The problem I have is that my output is only the last rows average and I want each row to provide me with a separate average.

Let me know if I should clarify more!

```
shortmeasurements = [ 300 301 303;

 301 302 nan;

 304 307 306;

 nan 303 306;

nan 301 nan;]
```

I think I'm getting an error from my `mean` line. `Tube` represents the *n*-by-*3* matrix I'm taking the average of.

```
failcount = 0; %//initialize variables
flag = false;


for n = (1:size(Tube,1)) %//number of elements in first row
    if all(isnan((Tube(1,:))))== 1 %// if all values in row 1 are NaN
        failcount = failcount + 1; %//fail count + 1

        if failcount == 1 %//first time through loop
            airSpeed = isnan; %//airspeed nan
        else 
            airSpeed(n,1) = (airSpeed( n-1,1)) %//previous air speed
        end
    else
        airSpeed = mean(Tube(n,~isnan(Tube(n,:)))); %//taking the mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in some lines you use

```
airSpeed(n, 1) = ...
```

but in others you use

```
airSpeed = ...
```

All of these lines should be

```
airSpeed(n, 1) = ...
```

otherwise you will overwrite the values and only store 1 value when you encounter

```
airSpeed = ...
```

and that is why only the mean of the last row is stored.

Comment: that worked! Thanks. IKavanagh would you happen to know how I could take the average of the rows with NaN's and have an output of a number. So if only two of the elements were numbers then I would only take the average of those two?   I thought "~isnan" would work?

Comment: @kal There are many ways, 1 is to use [`nanmean`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) from [Adriaan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32777780/1552737) applied to each row (or the whole matrix). `mean(Tube(5, ~isnan(Tube(5, :))))` should also work as it uses indexing to only return those values that are **not** `NaN`. If you want to stick with loops then you could loop through the elements in each row and sum those that are **not** `NaN` whilst also keeping a count of those that are **not** `NaN` and at the end of the loop compute the average with `airSpeed(n, 1) = sum / count;`.

Comment: So your saying recreate the matrix so that NaN's arn't in any rows and then take averages?  If that is the case wouldn't their be a problem in the different lengths of the rows?   Thanks

Comment: @kal No I'm not saying that. You are correct there would be issues in the lengths with removing `NaN`. I'm saying you only count and sum `NaN`.

Comment: @kal there indeed arises a problem with row length when you try to remove `NaN`, which means you'd have to loop over each row and create a temporary variable of the row without `NaN`s, get the mean of that and store it in your average array. `nanmean` does this in 7 characters and a lot faster than a loop.

Answer (score 5):

For averages without `nan` you can just use [`nanmean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html)

```
y = nanmean(shortmeasurements,dim)
```

where `shortmeasurements` is your dataset and `dim` specifies the dimension you want the average over. `1` sets is to averages per column (default) and `2` sets it to averages per row.

Thus, for your full dataset:

```
airspeed = nanmean(Tube,2);
```

and you do not have to do any additional checking for `nan`s using this single line.

Test run:

```
airspeed = nanmean(shortmeasurements,2)

airspeed =

  301.3333
  301.5000
  305.6667
  304.5000
  301.0000
```

If you do not have the Statistics toolbox installed, no worries! MathWorks have implemented the feature to omit nans from the search in [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) (and `max`, `min` etc) itself:

```
A = [1 0 0 1 NaN 1 NaN 0];
M = mean(A,'omitnan')
M = 
    0.5000
```

Comment: Warning: `nanmean` requires the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: @rayryeng - [you were saying...?](https://github.com/davidnbresch/climada/blob/master/code/nanmean.m) :)